# Relay PostgreSQL connection over another server

Tags: postgresql, proxy

I'm using a PostgreSQL database on a remote server with a very restrictive firewall that only allows connections from our webserver. This makes developing stuff on my own workstation pretty difficult, as I cannot connect to this server directly to test my code.

What I'd like to do is set up some sort of proxy on our webserver that simply sends all queries to the firewalled server. Then I can use our server from my workstation to test my code. Any ideas how to do this or other ways that solve my problem?

Comment: I'd call "I cannot connect to this server directly to test my code" a good thing, a very very good thing. You'd be better off testing against a local copy of the database or a remote staging server (which has a copy of the production data). Testing on a production database is just a shortcut to pain and suffering.

Comment: Don't worry, I have a staging server and the remote server uses a copy of the database for testing, I just cannot connect to it from home where I usualy work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

use ssh and create a local tunnel, something like this (only works if you have an ssh daemon running on web server)

```
ssh user@webserver.com -CNL localhost:5432:192.168.1.128:5432
```

The above will listen on 5432 (postgres port) on localhost and forward all traffic to remote machine via the web server.

As mentioned below by Ricky Han, you need to change the address **192.168.1.128** to that of your PostgreSQL server.

Obviously you will need to change the name of webserver.com as well! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot this was very easy, I got it working in no time! I added the remote server as an alias for locahost so I don't even have to change the connection string in the code.

Comment: ssh is probably the coolest pieces software in the world :-). It took me a while to realise how powerful it is, but now I use it all the time for tunnelling. I recently had exactly the same problem as you and solved it as above.

Comment: Replace 192.168.1.128 with your postgres IP address

Comment: Thanks A lot this  save my life ... i was struggling through using nginx proxy to do the same