# Access a postgresql instance set up on GCE from local host via proxy

Tags: django, postgresql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Can I access a PostgreSQL instance set up on Google Cloud Engine from my local host via Cloud SQL Proxy or another way?

I'm trying to move a PostgreSQL database from Cloud SQL to Compute Engine for testing purposes. So far, I 've been using Cloud SQL Proxy to run Django migrations on Cloud SQL from my local host, and I'd like to do the same with the database set up on GCE.

Comment: Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768913 it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access a postgresl instance set on Google Cloud Engine form local host.

You need to follow these steps:

1. Install PostgreSQL on a Compute Engine instance.
2. Configure PostgreSQL for remote access.
3. Configure a Cloud Platform firewall to open a port.
4. Connect to PostgreSQL from a remote computer.

[How to set up PostgreSQL on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That I can do without problem, but I'd need to access the GCE PostgreSQL by the way of a proxy, just like the cloud_sql_proxy does when you're using Google Cloud SQL.